# Maven pom.xml error jboss (quickstart file)

Tags: maven, jboss, redhat, jboss-developer-studio

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrTIy.jpg)

I'm using Redhat Developer Studio 12.0 and jboss EAP 7.1 for the server
I am trying first the quickstart (helloworld) (jboss), so I will 
know if everything works fine.
I am newbie to jboss that's what I really don't know much about it.

this is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
           <groupId>org.jboss.eap.quickstarts</groupId>
           <artifactId>quickstart-parent</artifactId>
           <version>7.1.0.GA</version>
           <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
       </parent>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>${qs.name.prefix} helloworld</name>
    <description>Helloworld</description>


    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope
            as the API is included in WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Servlet API, we use provided scope as the API is included in WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pom is looking for another parent pom in the upper directory

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.jboss.eap.quickstarts</groupId>
   <artifactId>quickstart-parent</artifactId>
   <version>7.1.0.GA</version>
   <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

The parent project have to exist in the path used by `<relativePath>`

Hope it helps!

Comment: <parent>
           <groupId>org.jboss.eap.quickstarts</groupId>
           <artifactId>quickstart-parent</artifactId>
           <version>7.1.0.GA</version>
           <relativePath>D:\Temp\jboss-eap-7.1.0.GA-quickstarts\helloworld\pom.xml</relativePath>
       </parent>   do you mean i need to path of the pom.xml where is it?

Comment: Your "main" project have a parent project (it is a different project), and that parent project is needed to compile and work. You need to put that parent project one directory above of your main project and you will have 2 poms: quickstart-parent/pom.xml and quickstart-parent/helloworld/pom.xms

Comment: @mavCan you tell me the details what I need to do?. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying ;) Your helloworld quickstart project is trying to find a parent project called "quickstart-parent" in an upper directory. Check if you have both projects and check the install notes of the quickstart please ;)